# top- and bottom-border with 100% height - how?

Tags: css

How can I have a top-and bottom margin that's at absoulute top and bottom if main content is less than 100% and at "end of scroll" if content if larger than screen?

Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/FGBZc/

(ie7 and up.)

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With box-sizing it would be the easiest.

Use `box-sizing: border-box` on that div. Give it a `min-height` of `100%`. Give it the `top` and `border-bottom` you want.

Here's the fiddle. -> http://jsfiddle.net/FGBZc/11/

Unfortuantely, it doesn't work on ie7. Just ie8+.

To do it without `box-sizing` requires some extra elements. It's the  sticky footer situation. If you google "sticky footer" you'll find what I did in the fiddle below.

Check it out -> http://jsfiddle.net/FGBZc/23/

Comment: Sweet. Works brilliantly, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try aligning it with a position absolute and then setting bottom to 0 in the css so:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```